# Transparent background for SVG

Tags: css, svg

I am working with SVGs, and would like to create one with a transparent background. The following example, should appear as just a white circle with a path in it. However, the whole 300px white canvas appears as a square, how do I get the result I want, as I can't really see where the canvas is defined?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" height="300" width="300" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="150.267" cy="149.854" r="111.303" fill-opacity="1"/>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,632.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill-opacity="1">
<path fill="#54534A" d="M2204.344,4414.691v-122.67h81.643h81.642l-1.237,6.804c-0.619,3.505-1.649,10.515-2.474,15.462l-1.443,8.659
        h-61.438h-61.644v38.141v38.141h54.635h54.635v16.493v16.494h-54.635h-54.635v36.079v36.08h60.613h60.407l1.443,10.515
        c0.825,5.979,2.062,13.401,2.68,16.493l1.237,5.979h-80.818h-80.612V4414.691z"/>

<!-- Other paths omitted -->
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Kudos for the minimal example :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted your question correctly... can you calrify the question?

Comment: @seahorsepip you're right apologies, but then, there is no white square, https://jsfiddle.net/v7pm9jth/ so it just felt into the "lack of [mcve]" close-vote reason.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, thats why I don't understand the question. He wants a white square and he does not whant a white square.. strange. Does anyone understand?

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo, I meant white *circle* with a transparent background.

Comment: @Kaiido Hmmm, the JS fiddle does seem to work - That's what I am after. However, when I use this file in my mobile app, I get the white square behind my circle. I'll post a pic in my question

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards yes, the svg is transparent by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears as a 300 x 300px rectangle with a transparent background here with a smaller white circle inside and the letter E(path).

You sure you're not giving the svg element a white background with CSS by accident?

The canvas is the `<svg>` element itself, you can change its background using CSS:

```
svg {
    background: red;
}
```